# What is an extension module in iptables?

Tags: command-line, iptables

The iptables manual page for `-m, --match match` is:

> Specifies a match to use, that is, an extension module that tests for a specific property. The set of matches make up the condition under which a target is invoked. Matches are evaluated first to last as specified on the command line and work in short-circuit fashion, i.e. if one extension yields false, evaluation will stop.

I do not understand what this means, specifically, what does the extension module mean?

Also, how is `iptables -A INPUT -m tcp ...` different from `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp ...` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Extension modules* are just that: they extend the capabilities of `iptables`.  For example, consider the `owner` module.  The iptable options `-m owner --uid-owner lp` will select all packets sent by user `lp`.  This feature is only available if you specify, as above, the `owner` module.   Likewise, the `tcp` module makes available options for selecting, among other things, tcp flags such as ACK or RST.  The available modules and their features are detailed in:

```
man iptables-extensions
```

---

**Also note that iptables is out-of-date. You should be using nftables instead.**